# Assigning map to char*.. how does this work? (Code-sample included)

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to work with some existing code and I came across this code that I don't quite understand how it works:

```
char *c_token = R(
{
  "1":"abcdef",
  "2":"ghijkl",
  "3":"mnopqr",
  "4":"stuvwx"
});
```

Where R() is defined as:

```
#define R(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

What does the c_token buffer look like after this?  Is there any advantage to doing this over just assigning a map<string,string>?  I am trying to read the code but I honestly don't understand what this is doing.

Assuming this was used to pass this map in, how would you translate this back into a map on the other end?

Comment: So why not try it? You sure tried to compile the code and print `c_token`. So what was the result? Can't you check it? `Is there any advantage to doing this over just assigning a map<string,string>?` It's comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages and will affect any answer. Your reference to `map` implies the code is C++ but it is not clear whether that is actually the case or whether that's just your own interpretation.

Comment: I dumped the buffer which ended up looking like a JSON object.
`{ "1":"abcdef", "2":"ghijkl", "3":"mnopqr", "4":"stuvwx" }`
So I understand what it's doing.  Maybe I just don't understand how it's doing it.

Comment: probably needs `const`.  e.g.:  `const char *c_token =` ...

Comment: Cool trick, sort of. Until you need a `)` in the text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding JSON as a string in C++ code using preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082004/embedding-json-as-a-string-in-c-code-using-preprocessor)

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is converting everything between the parentheses including the commas to a string literal.  It can be almost complete syntactic garbage. e.g.: This is fine.  `R(!@#,*&#,(,));`

As an experiment, try:

```
#define R(...) "BEGIN" #__VA_ARGS__ "END"
```

This yields: `"BEGIN!@#,*&#,(,)END"`

and compare what happens when you just do:

```
#define R(x) "BEG" #x "END"
```

This yields: `"BEGIN!@#END"` with a warning something like:

> too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'R'

Comment: Thanks.  That answers it.  I was trying to understand what/how it was doing that.  I noticed that it skips line breaks though.  So #__VA_ARGS__ will ignore line breaks?

Comment: I believe the rules about spacing in the preprocessor are that any non-zero amount of whitespace (outside of string or character literals) including newlines is expanded to a single space.

Comment: And string literals separated by whitespace are concatenated (in [phase 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)).

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) by the preprocessor.  Whatever appears as the argument(s) to `R()` is converted to a string.  The `#` in front of the argument(s) to the macro is syntax that causes this.

So `R("foo", abc!@#)` becomes string string literal `"\"foo\", abc!@#"`.  Newlines and leading whitespace will be converted to a single space.

The reason to do this is to make a string with lots of `"` in it easier to write by not needing to escape them and to allow for easier line wrapping.  If you simply wrote the jSON string directly, every `"` would need to be written as `\"` to keep it from delimiting the string. Each line would also need to end the string and begin a new one on the next line, since you can't have line breaks inside a string literal.

So the example would be written as:

```
const char *c_token = 
"{"
  "\"1\":\"abcdef\","
  "\"2\":\"ghijkl","
  "\"3\":\"mnopqr","
  "\"4\":\"stuvwx""
"}";
```

Which is rather more complex that the more natural syntax the macro allowed.